# Symfony2 | Добавлиние id пользователя при создании или обновлении формы

Tags: symfony2, update, doctrine2, symfony3, fosuserbundle

Добрый день.
Столкнулся с проблемой.
Есть у меня, скажем, "Пост", и я хочу добавить к нему ID пользователя, который его создал и кто его в последний раз изменял.
Не совсем понимаю как сделать это. И так же какую связь использовать при этом(OneToMany?). Использую fosuserbundle.

Comment: Два поля сделайте у поста: 1) `создатель` 2) `редактор`. Каждое поле связано Many-To-One с User. Про реализацию посмотрите в документации [associations](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html) и [association-mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html) ...

Comment: Спасибо, я так и сделал. Только  вопрос, использовать PreUpdate при редакции и PrePersist при добавлении? Потому что, добавить автора надо только при добавлении поста, и в последствии заблокировать изменения этого поля. Ну и наоборот для редактора.

Comment: Ну это детали реализации, если у вас есть много вариантов как может быть обновлен пост, то можно и `preUpdate` с `prePersist` сделать, в самом простом случае просто в контроллере `$post->setOwner($user);` или `$post->setEditor($user);`

Comment: @danil спасибо. Тут я серьезно затупил что-то. Аж стыдно...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это был мой глупейший вопрос.

Достаточно в контроллере для:

newAction - во время добавления в базу данных(тзн. после submit) добавить `$meeting->setMentor($this->getUser());`

а для editAction - при submit `$meeting->setWhoUpdated($this->getUser());`.

В форму значения этих переменных добавлять не следует.